# 'myTable' is not associated to Model

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on an express sequelize project.

I've got an issue with sequelize.

I've got a simply schema like the documentation says:

```
class Task extends Model {}
Task.init({ title: Sequelize.STRING }, { sequelize, modelName: 'task' });
class User extends Model {}
User.init({ username: Sequelize.STRING }, { sequelize, modelName: 'user' });

User.hasMany(Task); // Will add userId to Task model
Task.belongsTo(User); // Will also add userId to Task model
```

But when I'm querying with include

```
sequelize.models['task'].findAll({include:[{all:true}]});
```

I'm facing to some issues:

The first :

```
this._getIncludedAssociation is not a function
```

Here is the github source origin code : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js#L615

I just change `this` to `Model` to check.

This error is gone away, but a second (linked with the first, because I changed the behaviour), appears

```
User is not associated to Model
```

But It should say `User is not associated to Task`

(github of error: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js#L711)

It's like the class Model wasn't instanciate...

What could be bad in my code ? Maybe the fact to call the model by `sequelize.models[modelName]` ?? I'm struggling with this for a long time...

Thanks.

---

More Infos :

**Sequelize Version** : ^5.7.0

**Architecture** :

At the application launch, all my models are store in a custom Database class stored in my process.

Inside any controller, I call a repository class with for exemple a method like the following where the wanted model is accessible via `this.model`:

```
findAll(options, force = false) {
        let data = this.performExtraOptions(options);
        data.paranoid = force;

        if (this.isDebug) {
                this.req.debug.addDatabaseCall('Table ' + this.model.getTableName() + ' findAll', data);

        }
        return this.model.findAll(data);
}
```

---

When I inspect with Chrome Debugger, the model is show like this :
`const model = class extends Model {};`

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the version of the sequelize you're using? I've tried the same situation and it works fine, I use 5.7.1. If necessary, I could show you the sample codes and the result.

Comment: Of Course :  "sequelize": "^5.7.0"

Comment: Could you debug or print the JSON of "this.model" to see if it is the object you expected?

Comment: @troy That's done

Comment: I'm confused, it was a backend server, how could you use Chrome Debugger? Let's continue this discussion in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192197/problem-of-using-sequelize

Comment: You're welcome, https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: Can you provide an mcve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

In reading the sequelize code, I found that the `options.model` is required inside the algo.

The problem was that I sent the model too in the query options, but as the model name (string).

The algo, transform the option.model as the instance object of `Model` to make the process.

So I just have to rename my variable passed as query options.

This line of code was the problem :
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js#L493

```
 if (!options.model) options.model = this;
```